# Run an executable on all the files in a folder (with subfolders)

Tags: bash, shell

I have an executable `test` which takes a `.txt` file as input, for example, we can run in a terminal `./test input.txt > result.txt`

I have also a folder `folder` which contains subfolders and `.txt` files.

I would like to write a bash to do the following task: **go through all the `.txt` inside `folder`, run the executable on it, and put the result in a separated file.**

For instance, for `folder\subfolder1\01-input.txt`, I would like to put the result in a file named `subfolder1_01-input.txt` (the result is not necessarily named like this, the names are just used to differentiate the results and allow me to trace back to the corresponding input file).

All the results can be put together in a big folder called `results`.

Does anyone know how to write this bash?

In the first place, to simplify the problem, we could assume that: there is only 1 level of subfolders in `folder`, and all the `.txt` inputs are placed under a subfolder of `folder`.

Comment: What have you tried? You should read at least a beginner's tutorial or do some googling. This kind of question has been asked a million times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for foldername in folder/*; do cd "$foldername"; for filename in *.txt; do ../../test "$filename" > output_"$filename"; done ; cd ../..; done
```

Note the output filename does not conform to your spec, this exercise is left to the reader ;-)

Comment: Mind the quoting: `"$foldername"`, `"$filename"`, `output_"$filename"`

Answer (score -1):

```
find $topleveldir -type f -exec sh -c 'file="{}"; log="${file//\//_}".txt; log="${log/#.}" ; echo $file $log ; ./test $file > $log' \;
```

If in doubt put the redirect in a script wrapper and just do a raw -exec ie

```
find $toplevel -type f -exec testwithitsownrediect.sh {} \;
```

I am assuming bash AND gun find

Comment: -1: indeed! You should check your answers before submitting. `-exec` doesn't take a shell script, but execvp-like arguments...

Comment: @JoSo OTOH `find` is the right way to do this, possibly also with a `-name \*.txt`